# How to open a website from an app to Safari using the URL stored in an array?

Tags: arrays, ipad, safari, nsurl

Hi guys i am working on an iPad app and i need some advice.

i have an array which stores users online information, and one of the data is a URL.
The list of information is shown in the master detail table view and once selected it will populate the detail view to show all its information, one of each is the URL. I want to be able to go to that shown URL by clicking on a button which will bring me to Safari and display that webpage.

below is the problem:

```
-(IBAction)loginClicked:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"loginClicked");

//--What should i replace indexPath.row with so that it will point to the current selected row?
loginObj = [appDelegate.loginArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//--if the above indexPath.row is replaced with an integer, the NSLog is able to print out the correct URL of that row
NSLog(@"URL = %@", loginObj.loginURL);

//--then when i insert loginObj.loginURL, it gives me error "too many arguments method to call, expected 1, have 2" but when i insert a proper URL @"http://www.google.com" it has no problem opening it up.
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"%@", loginObj.loginURL]];

}
```

loginURL is declared as NSString in my class.

i am using SDK4.2 iOS5, iPad master detail view template with storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Declare an integer like the below in your interface file,

```
int theCurrentSelectedRow;
```

In your didSelectRow method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
   theCurrentSelectedRow = indexPath.row; 
}
```

Alter your method as below,

```
-(IBAction)loginClicked:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"loginClicked");

loginObj = [appDelegate.loginArray objectAtIndex:theCurrentSelectedRow];

NSLog(@"URL = %@", loginObj.loginURL);

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"%@", loginObj.loginURL]];

}
```

The idea is to store the current selected row index in a global var and access use it in your method.

Answer (score 0):

`+[NSURL URLWithString:]` does not support variadic arguments. You should be receiving a compiler warning at least, that this bit of code is **incorrect**:

```
[NSURL URLWithString: @"%@", loginObj.loginURL]
```

Instead, to construct a URL, simply:

```
[NSURL URLWithString:loginObj.loginURL]
```

Even better, update your model classes to deal with `NSURL` directly.